# WGS84 with elevation z

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84

I need to define a data structure which for convenience reasons for users using my software should be related to WGS84 - if possible. So that it makes it easy for users to use my software, convert from e.g. GPS data they get from Android or iOS system calls, and convert these forth and back to "my" coordinates.

However, my mapping application uses various UTM projections, depending which part of the world is shown. Thus I want to abstract away the need for a user to deal with various projections.

Ideally I just provide WGS84 as single projection - but I need height(!) since this is a 3D application and objects are on different floors with different elevation.

I've read some article here detailing about elevation here: https://geozoneblog.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/wgs84-versus-nad83-vertical/

What is the best way to provide WGS84 with elevation info, or shouldn't I do this?

Comment: I think you have two questions here. The first is about how to define or choose some coordinate reference system (or compound CRS) that includes a height component, the second is how to hold the 3-D coordinates​, so that you can use it in your application

Comment: I'm using 3D coordinates already in our 3D indoor map. It's about using a coordinate system like WGS84 with an elevation model, like e.g. http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Altitude (we use "local"). I've now added a "local" elevation model and 2 "wgs84" elevation model as type - but I'm still not 100% certain this is the best approach.

Comment: If you already have 3-D coordinates, don't you already have a defined data structure?